# Custom site column Hyperlink with C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, development, column, site-column

I have to create Custom Column of **Hyperlink** with C#

I have used following field to create the column but it wont work, It shows the picture icon- as
[image]

How to fix it?

```
<Field ID="{F6D62881-C8B2-417D-880C-B797C5481604}"
Name="Link1" Hidden="FALSE" Sealed="TRUE" StaticName="Link1"
DisplayName="Link 7" Type="URL" Format="Hyperlink" Required="FALSE" Group="Test" AllowHyperlink="TRUE"></Field>
```

Comment: Can you ignore `AllowHyperlink` and try?

Comment: valid xml of hyperlink looks like      
**"<Field Type=\"URL\" 
        DisplayName=\"Photo\" 
        Required=\"FALSE\" 
        EnforceUniqueValues=\"FALSE\" 
        Indexed=\"FALSE\" 
        Format=\"Hyperlink\" 
        ID=\"{0ab532c6-bcc9-4a33-a5ce-35020406accd}\" 
        SourceID=\"{fef8ec49-4647-4a62-bcd7-f397110b6f2c}\" 
        StaticName=\"Photo\" 
        Name=\"Photo\" 
        ColName=\"nvarchar6\" 
        RowOrdinal=\"0\" 
        ColName2=\"nvarchar7\" 
        RowOrdinal2=\"0\" Version=\"2\" />"**. My column name is `Photo`

Comment: Type is hyperlink

Comment: I have changed Type to Hyperlink and still have the same issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer-
We don't need **Sealed="TRUE"**, this causes issue while creating the Field of Hyperlink type. Thanks for the above comment answers.

```
<Field ID="{F6D62881-C8B2-417D-880C-B797C5481604}"
Name="Link1" Hidden="FALSE" StaticName="Link1"
DisplayName="Link 7" Type="URL" Format="Hyperlink" Required="FALSE" Group="Test"></Field>
```